# How to apply WHERE clause to a RECORD REPEATED

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table composed like that:

```
-header
-data
-----createdAt
-----attributes
---------------key
---------------value
```

where `data` is a type `RECORD` in mode `NULLABLE` and `attributes` is a type `RECORD` in mode `REPEATED`.

I would like to make a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
WHERE data.createdAt >= "2021-08-13 10:44:00.000 UTC" 
AND data.attributes.key = "key name"
AND data.attributes.value IS null
```

That clearly I can't.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out docs - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#scanning_for_values_that_satisfy_a_condition

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

For the records, this should work:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `table` 
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST (data.attributes) as attributes
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM UNNEST(data.attributes) AS attributes
        WHERE attributes.attributeKey = "key name"
        AND attributes.attributeValue IS NULL    
    )
    AND data.createdAt >= "2021-08-13 10:44:00.000 UTC"
```

or also

```
   SELECT *
   FROM `table`
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST (data.attributes) as attributes
   WHERE attributes.attributeKey = "key name"
   AND attributes.attributeValue IS NULL
   AND data.createDateTime >= "2021-08-13 10:44:00.000 UTC"
```